# BehaviorSubject doesn't execute when the variable changes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am not sure if I understand the usage of a `BehaviorSubject`, but what I want to do is watch a variable for change, and this variable is a **two-way binding variable** attached to `<input type="file">`. When the input changes I want to execute a function that will automatically upload the file.

```html
<input type="file" [(ngModel)]="presentationService.fileSelected">
```

The component I am using looks like this:

```js
@Component({
    selector: '...',
    templateUrl: '...'
})
export class CreatePresentationStep1 {
    public constructor(public presentationService: PresentationService) { }
}
```

The service looks like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class PresentationService {
    public fileSelected?: File;

    public constructor() {
        this.handlers();
    }

    private handlers(): void {
        new BehaviorSubject<File>(this.fileSelected).subscribe({
            next: (file) => {
                console.log('file', file);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When the component loads, the console log runs and prints `file undefined`, which is correct. When I click on the input field and select a file, the behavior never runs again. Is that intended? I would expect the call to run again since the variable changed. How can I get my behavior to run every time the variable changes?

Comment: Its always better to use BehaviorSubject when you know the initial value.
That being said.
The BehaviorSubject is updated by passing in the next value. fileSelected$.next(newValue). The BS you have is a readonly property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not really how a `BehaviorSubject` works. What you pass in the constructor is just the default initial value. It cannot monitor a property. In your case, this code should work:

```
<input type="file" [ngModel]="presentationService.fileSelected$ | async" 
       (ngModelChange)="presentationService.fileSelected$.next($event)">

@Component({
    selector: '...',
    templateUrl: '...'
})
export class CreatePresentationStep1 {
  constructor(public presentationService: PresentationService) { }
}

@Injectable()
export class PresentationService {
    public readonly fileSelected$ = new BehaviorSubject<File | void>(void 0);

    public constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {
        this.handlers();
    }

    private handlers(): void {
      this.fileSelected$.subscribe({
        next: (file) => {
          console.log('file', file);
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Although this is not entirely like I would do it. This gives consumers of your `PresentationService` full access to the subject/observable, but it's one way :)

Comment: `this.fileSelected.subscribe` should have a `$` right? Also, what does the `$` convention  represent?

Comment: I get an error with `.update($event)`, however `.next($event)` works is that what it should be?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I'm sorry, it was late for me :) You are right, it should be `.next()`. Also the `$` is a convention. Which dictates that it's an observable stream. It's a dollar sign because you pronounce it as 's', which makes most variables plural. For instance `file$` indicates that it's a stream which will have more files over time, but just one at a certain frame of time. Now it's early here, so I don't know if I explained it well :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`<input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)">`

Bind event listener in component:

```
@Component({
    selector: '...',
    templateUrl: '...'
})
export class CreatePresentationStep1 {
    public constructor(public presentationService: PresentationService) { }
    public fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any) {
      const file = fileInput.target.files[0];
      this.presentationService.handlers(file).subscribe(file => console.log('file', file));
   }
}
```

And in Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class PresentationService {
    public fileSelected?: File;
    private handlersSubject= new BehaviorSubject<File>(undefined);
    public handlerObs$ = this.handlersSubject.asObservable();

    public handlers(file: any): void {
        this.handlersSubject.next(file);
    }
}
```